# Can't keep order as input in Plotly by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I use ggplot2 then use ggplotly to draw.
But the order in X axis always by colour or shape.
How can I let the order in letter of x, not in colour or shape?
My code is as following.
Thanks

Plotly address : https://plot.ly/~jonwenjen/11/bin165-vs-wafer-id/

Code :

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
library(proto)
library(gsubfn)
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(sqldf)
library(tcltk)
library(tcltk2)
library(reshape2)
library(tag)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
test = "select Tracetime,Test_Site,Wafer_id,User,Bin165 from file  order by Wafer_id   "
d <- read.csv.sql("data.csv", sql = test)
d$Wafer_id <- factor(d$Wafer_id, levels = unique(as.character(d$Wafer_id)))
p <-ggplot(d,aes(x=Wafer_id,y=Bin165, colour = User , group = Wafer_id)) + geom_point(alpha=0.7) 
h <- ggplotly (p)
h
```

Comment: Can you provide a *minimal reproducible* example? (No need to load all those packages I would think.) Also, does the ordering work in ggplot, or is it only a problem in plotly?

Comment: It only happen in plotly. In ggplot2 it's ok.

Comment: Minimal : https://plot.ly/~jonwenjen/14/bin165-vs-wafer-id/